# How to add multiple singer name or genre to single mp3 songs metadata

Tags: mp3, audio-player, android-music-player

What is the best way to add multiple genre/Singer/Artist to MP3 song's metadata(tag), so that the music-player can pick it correctly.

```
For Example:

Title: Gerua
Artist:  Antara Mitra, Arijit Singh
```

Then in Artist section of Music Player it should show 2 Artist

```
       ARTIST
 1. Antara Mitra
 2. Arijit Singh
```

instead of

```
    ARTIST
1. Antara Mitra, Arijit Singh
```

Is it possible or any other alternative for this purpose?